# How to compare all nested child elements length with each other?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 1 object which contains nested child like below:

```
$scope.artists.materials.items[] //contains list of items
```

Now I would have several artist which will contains list of items but in this I want to check total length of each item of artists and if mismatch found then I want to return true or false.

**For eg**: I have 2 artist and from this Artist1 contains 2 items and Artist2 contains only 1 item then this is a mismatch as I want to have both the artist to contains same number of items.

But here I am confused with how do i do all this comparison in AngularJS way.

**Code:**

```
 function checkItemsValidity() {
        angular.forEach($scope.artists, function (artist) {
            alert(artist.materials.items.length);
        });
    }
```

How can I do this in better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all artists have to have the same number of `items`, then just store the length of the `items` from the first artist and make sure all of them have that same `items` length. Something like:

**Updated with suggestions from comments**

```
function checkItemsValidity() {
    var itemsLength = $scope.artists[0].materials.items.length;
    angular.forEach($scope.artists, function (artist) {
        if(artist.materials.items.length != itemsLength) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You're unnecessarily going through everything after a found difference.

Comment: Hence the "Something like" qualifier. The OP is free to optimize as necessary.

Comment: Sure. However, the OP is probably a beginner since this is what he/she needs help with, so better not teach sloppy practices.

Comment: Thank  you so much lex for your kind help.thanks alot and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 0):

An improvement to Lex's answer: no need for the `isValid` variable, if there's no reason to go through the rest once the first difference is found.

```
function checkItemsValidity() {
  var len = $scope.artists[0].materials.items.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.artists.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.artists[i].materials.items.length != len) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank  you so much Roope for your kind help.thanks alot and please keep helping like this :)